# How to handle a ScrollableView with dozens of views?

Tags: javascript, android, titanium

I have a `ScrollableView` in Titanium (targeting only Android) that has to scroll through a few dozen views. Each view is about a paragraph or two of text, with maybe an image or two.

I'm worried that it would be too stressful on the CPU to populate all the views right from the start. So, my plan was to only have 3 views actually in the ScrollableView at a time.

Here is a solution I came up with. Views are numbered 1 to 10. The bold numbered view is the one currently active. The dashes are placeholders. When the user views the first view:

> **1** 2 3 - - - - - - -

The user scrolls right.

> 1 **2** 3 - - - - - - -

The user scrolls right again, and view 1 is removed. View 4 is now added to the ScrollableView in anticipation.

> - 2 **3** 4 - - - - - -

And so on.

The obstacle I face with this is that, as far as I can tell, there is no way to insert views before the existing ones (as would be the case of scrolling *left*).

How should I implement this?

Comment: you need to find the titanium equivalent of an AdapterView. Im not familiar with titanium at all so I wouldn't know what that is. But using an AdapterView (such as ListView) with an adapter will handle all of the logic that you've laid here out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created [a Titanium module](https://bitbucket.org/MostThingsWeb/virtualscroller/wiki/Home), based off of [this GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/810171), that does just this.

Usage is like so:

```
var VirtualScroller = require('ui/common/VirtualScroller');

var virtualScroller = VirtualScroller({
    itemCount: 10,
    start: 0,
    getView: function(i) {
        return Titanium.UI.createLabel({
            width: Titanium.UI.FILL,
            height: Titanium.UI.FILL,
            text: "This is item " + (i + 1)
        });
    },
    isInfinite: false
});

window.add(virtualScroller.view);
```

The module works by controlling a ScrollableView with three views (like the original gist). It supports finite (above example) and infinite scrolling.

I've posted details [on my blog](http://www.mostthingsweb.com/2012/07/virtualscroller-a-titanium-module-supporting-memory-efficient-finite-and-infinite-scrolling/), and it's available [at BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/MostThingsWeb/virtualscroller/wiki/Home).

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest using a ListView. You can configure it so that there are no dividers. It handles scrolling internally, so you don't need a ScrollView wrapper. It also manages the loading of content so that only what is visible at the current scroll position needs to be in memory.

Comment: This sounds perfect. Do you mean `ScrollView` instead of `ListView`? I'm using Titanium, not Java. Hopefully, [ScrollView](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Titanium.UI.ScrollView) does the memory trick that you mentioned.

Comment: @SimpleCoder - I meant a ListView instead of ScrollView. I don't know whether Titanium has a ListView equivalent, however.

Comment: @SimpleCoder - Hmm. According to [this link](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/129214/how-to-add-listview) there is no ListView equivalent in Appcelerator (a.k.a. Titanium). Instead, you're supposed to use a tableView. I have no idea if Titanium maps that to a ListView or whether it is clever like ListView about what it loads into memory.